# Etymologically why do some words have explicit potential sense while others don't have?

Tags: etymology

Consider the following pairs,

- can hear: 聞ける (the potential of 聞く) and 聞こえる
- can see: 見られる (the potential of 見る) and 見える

I am interested to know the etymologies of how some words have explicit potential forms while other words do not have. What are their purposes? I think it is redundant.

## Bonus

Is there any terminology used to refer to words having explicit potential sense?

Comment: Strictly speaking, 聞こえる and 見える are 自発(spontaneous)動詞, not 可能(potential)動詞.

Answer (score 3):

見える and 聞こえる come from classical forms 見ゆ and 聞こゆ. These potentials would be natural to those verbs, but they've survived past the originals' death.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'natural to those verbs'. I would say that they used to be applicable to all verbs and no longer are.

Comment: I mean, /miyu/ would logically have potential /miyeru/, and since there's no /ye/ it's /mieru/.

Comment: 見える came from 見ゆる, which is the attributive form of 見ゆ, not the potential.

Comment: @user4092, Shogakukan's 国語大辞典's entry for 見える gives a derivation from 見ゆ, not 見ゆる.  見ゆ is described as the 自発形 of 見る.